# How to fail a spark application when there is an error

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to make my Spark application fail, while I encounter an error ( like my file line count is less than 10, it a logical error for my business logic) . I am doing a System.exit(20), but when I am checking status of the application in yarn (yarn application -status ) it shows succeeded, I want to see failed instead . I am automating things using shell script, but this behavior is an hindrance for me.

Will you please help me , how can I grace fully fail my spark application , so that yarn application status will be failed .

NOTE: I am running spark in yarn cluster mode

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If your code is in Java you can call the method `stop()` on your `JavaSparContex`, like so:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf(); 
JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

javaSparkContext.sc().taskScheduler().stop();
```